# Angular passing misc symbols

Tags: javascript, angularjs, utf-8

I am trying to pass a `&#9733;` (★) as a parameter however when I attempt it I get:

```
syntax Error: Token ''★★' is not a valid identifier'
```

Here is my code:

```
<question-rating-stats
        rating-data="{values:[15,15,20,20,30], labels:['&#9733;'.'&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;'], avg: 3.5}"
        question="{question: 'Give me stars'}">

</question-rating-stats>
```

So my question is how do I pass these parameters?

Comment: between your first and second index in your labels array there is a `.`(dot) instead of `,`(comma)

Comment: instead of a comma you have put a dot (this might not be the actual issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the "." sign in your label array. If what you want is a concatenation, use `+`. If there are two items, use `,`:

```
labels:['&#9733;' + '&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;','&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;']
```

In javascript, `.` is used to access properties of an `object`. Here, it tries to access a property of `★★`, which is obviously a string, not an object.